# How to upload .tif image file?

Tags: 7, media

I want to upload image(.tif extension) to drupal website, but as per current we can upload only jpg/jpeg/png/gif only.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Display TIFF image in all web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser) unless you're on Safari, you will not be able to render the `.tif` image on your site.

Therefore, this more like a file rather than an image. If you want to upload it, for your field type use file instead of image.

If you plan to display/render the `.tif` image, you will have to convert it to a known image file: `.png, .jpeg, .gif`, etc..

---

**Edit:**

> Do we have any drupal module that can convert .tif to other image
>   extension? – [Govind](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201137/how-to-upload-tif-image-file/201139?noredirect=1#comment243303_201139#comment-243303)

According to [Henk's comment in Upload tif using image API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1210962#comment-7518707) there is a way:

> I was looking for a similar solution and found a working solution in
>   Drupal 7 to upload, scale and display tiff images.
>
> Install [ImageMagick](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagemagick) module and its dependencies **with ImageMagick tif
>   support on the server**
>
> Install [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module
>
> Use the media module as the widget type for your image type field
>   because the regular image widget type does not support TIFF's, with
>   that you should be able to upload tiff images in Drupal
>
> And i forgot...add the "change file format to : png" for your image
>   style because only Safari is capable of displaying tiff's directly

Comment: Do we have any drupal module that can convert .tif to other image extension?

Comment: @Govind updated my answer